# Modifier to custom directive in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with custom directives and want to create one such that you could use separate events for firing it based on what you pass it in the markup.

```
v-example-directive.mousedown="exampleFunction"
v-example-directive.mouseup="exampleFunction"
v-example-directive.click="exampleFunction"
```

I've looked through Vues Documentation and tried searching how to do this but have found nothing about this. Is this something that could be done such that you can create one directive and have either multiple functions inside or the ability to define what type of event you want? Or would I have to register multiple directives to achieve this?

Comment: What extra work does your directive do that `@click`, `@mousedown`, and `@mouseup` do not already do?

Comment: Well specifically there are cases like Electron and other places where the click event doesn't bubble up such that you can add a listener but mousedown or mouseup might. Electron is not the only example but adding this functionality would make it more robust.

Comment: Also the directive being used is more being used for the sake of code reduction so that it's defined in one place and then can just be referenced throughout and be easy to understand.

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EddNLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `args` or `modifiers` in your custom vue directive.

To use these hooks, you have to look at the `binding` parameter of the directive. This parameter includes [a whole set of properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) that you can use to bake your custom directive.

In your case, you would want to look for either the `binding.modifier` or `binding.arg` depending on the HTML structure you desire:

> Argument markup: `<img v-example-directive:mouseup>`
>
> Modifier markup: `<img v-example-directive.mouseup>`

Now that you have added a "flag", you can check for it in the directive:

```
Vue.directive('example-directive', {
  bind(el, binding) {
    if (binding.arg == 'mouseup') {} // Using argument markup
    if (binding.modifiers.mouseup) {} // Using modifier markup
  }
})
```

Example:

```js
Vue.directive('example-directive', {
    bind(el, binding) {
        if (binding.arg == 'mousedown') { // Check by argument given to directive
          el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
            binding.value() // The function provided by the directive
          });
        }else if (binding.modifiers.mouseup) { //check by modifier 
          el.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            binding.value()
          });
        }
    }
})

let x = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log("clicked")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-example-directive:mousedown="clicked">mousedown</button>
<button v-example-directive.mouseup="clicked">mouseup</button>
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted, however if i wanted to add a default case would i just have if (arg == '')?

Comment: A default case would be just whatever inside the `bind` function

Comment: Correct in what way @petey? I use arguments for stuff like this (directive:arg), I have never used modifiers (directive.modifier) before. As of making this answer, I realized that it works too.. But I do not know if this is what it is intended to do.

Comment: Is there any benefit of checking by argument over checking by modifier or vice versa? And is there any benefit of using : over . (in the markup) or vice versa?

Comment: I think the proper way is to create arguments for functionality (When you give values to the component as in a function, string...) Then if you want to do something slightly different on the same function, you can slam on a modifier. 
I found this example to explaining: `<button v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">`

Comment: @SølveTornøe `Correct in what way`  I was wondering about the difference in the two lines (one uses `:` and the next uses `.`)